# Do F-22 and F-35 use force sensing flight sticks like F-16?

Tags: f-16, f-35, f-22, sidestick

Do F-22 and F-35 use [force sensing flight sticks](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/68278/14897) (as opposed to flight sticks that actually deflect and sense movement), like F-16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They move, pretty much like an F-16 stick.

From this [MIT lecture "F-22 Flight Controls"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-687-private-pilot-ground-school-january-iap-2019/class-videos/special-lecture-f-22-flight-controls/), Lt Col Randy Gordon, F-22 test pilot (from the transcript):

> It's a side stick.
>
> Initially it didn't move.
>
> Eventually they decided, I'll put in some deflection.
>
> So I can go a half inch left, a half inch right, about a quarter inch
> forward, I go about a half inch back because normally I really want to
> get the nose going this way.
>
> There's some deflection to give you feedback that you've input
> something on the stick, but not so much deflection that it gets in the
> way of everything else you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for that edit. I was just about to do that.

Comment: AFAIK, the "didn't move" lesson was learned on early F-16. The F-22 stick was movable (but force-sensing) from the beginning.

Comment: Yes. And I believe that is what he is referring to in the presentation. Of course, we'd have to ask him for specifics.